# Installing Geopandas for Docker image. Python:3.8.10-slim-buster

Tags: python, docker, geopandas

I'm currently stuck at trying to install geopandas in a docker image. I'm currently using python:3.8.10-slim-buster.

Here is my docker file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifkW2.png)

Here is are my error messages:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmCzL.png)

Can you guys please help me out? Thank you!

Comment: Please post your Dockerfile and error messages as text rather than images

Answer (score 0):

I think the environment variable is not set inside the container. An easier way to build this is to just run the base image.

docker run -itd --name python python:3.8.10-slim-buster bash
(This can be any image)

The container will run in the detected mode so go inside the container using the below command.

docker exec -it python bash

you can manually run all the dependencies inside the container and commit it as a new image

docker commit

Now, this can be used as a base image.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error on an M1 Mac. To fix it, add `--platform=linux/amd64` to the docker build command.

Another way is to add it in the FROM directive so you don't have to always pass it in docker build:

`FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.8-slim`